# xamarin forms change the selected Tab color Text

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I'm using Xamarin cross plat form tab page.
I want to changed the selected tab color text.
I can changed the background andtext color. 
**I need to change the selected Tab color Text.**
this is my code

```
var page = new tabPage()
                    {
                        BarBackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke,
                        BarTextColor = Color.Black
                    };


<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ABCAPP.Views.MainPage"  >
    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

    <ContentPage Title="ALL"  >
    </ContentPage>

<ContentPage Title="Email"   >
</ContentPage>

 <ContentPage Title="phoe"   >
</ContentPage>
```

If we select "Email",  I want to change the "Email" ,text color. 
How do I do it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xaml code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
         x:Class="App3.MainPage"
        BarBackgroundColor="Yellow"> 
    <local:Page1/>
    <local:Page1/>
</TabbedPage>
```

For Android:

Use `app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/accent_material_light"` and
`app:tabTextColor="@color/accent_material_dark"` properties to change text color of selected tab.(Remove `BarTextColor = Color.Black` from your code that you have provided.)

Inside your Resources folder -> layout Folder -> Tabbar.axml

Place below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/accent_material_light"
app:tabTextColor="@color/accent_material_dark"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Hope this may solve your issue.